# OpenGL Google Maps Like Navigation

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es

I would like to create an application using OpenGL ES (in ObjC) allowing user to navigate into a detailled 2D map (pan, scale, rotate) using Gesture Recognizers.

I have, like Google Maps, a folder containing 128x128 textures for every "chunk" and LOD Level, for example, LOD 0 = 1 texture, LOD 1 = 4 textures, LOD 2 = 16 textures, etc...
Depending on the scale/zoom, I can switch LOD to show more details...

How would you implement something like that, technically ?

For example, how to load/unload textures has needed (NSOperationQueue ? What will happen if user zoom & dezoom and/or pan very fast ?), how to switch LOD, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the [WWDC 2010 Session#104](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) presentation and its [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) demo code. It goes into some detail about using tiles in a UIScrollView and handles zooming, etc.